# What is the problem with the following output?

Tags: python, ansible, switch-statement, cisco

Every time I start my playbook I get an error. I figured out it is a problem with the ios_config module and maybe Python.

I got the information from radius, that the username is authenticated and this seems to work.

I just want a simple configuration change in the first step.

```
Playbook.yaml
---
- name: Basic Show Commands
  hosts: SWITCH
  gather_facts: False
  connection: local


  tasks:
    - name: add vlan
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - vlan 3219
```

`Ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
transport = local
hostfile = ./hosts
host_key_checking = False
timeout = 5
```

Run Command:

```
sudo ansible-playbook -u A-USERNAME-N  -k play.yaml -c paramiko (Username is written like this)
```

The Error looks like this:

```
ansible-playbook 2.5.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/admin1/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: [defaults]hostfile option, The key is misleading as it can also be a list of hosts, a directory or a list of paths , use [defaults]
inventory=/path/to/file|dir instead. This feature will be removed in version 2.8. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
SSH password:
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: play.yaml ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in play.yaml

PLAY [Basic Show Commands] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [add vlan] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/play.yaml:25
<10.1.103.60> using connection plugin network_cli (was local)
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_config.py
<10.1.103.60> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.1.103.60> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<10.1.103.60> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971="` echo /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971 `" ) && sleep 0'
<10.1.103.60> PUT /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-21017N44pTj/tmpWR4cIJ TO /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971/ios_config.py
<10.1.103.60> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971/ /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971/ios_config.py && sleep 0'
<10.1.103.60> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971/ios_config.py && sleep 0'
<10.1.103.60> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/admin1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553866282.25-60687928596971/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/ios/ios.py", line 114, in get_config
KeyError: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_module_ios_config.py", line 573, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_module_ios_config.py", line 476, in main
    config, have_banners = get_running_config(module, config)
  File "/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_module_ios_config.py", line 374, in get_running_config
    contents = get_config(module, flags=flags)
  File "/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/ios/ios.py", line 117, in get_config
  File "/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line 149, in __rpc__
ansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: show running-config all
                ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

DE003SW01#

fatal: [10.1.103.60]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/ios/ios.py\", line 114, in get_config\nKeyError: ''\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_module_ios_config.py\", line 573, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_module_ios_config.py\", line 476, in main\n    config, have_banners = get_running_config(module, config)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_module_ios_config.py\", line 374, in get_running_config\n    contents = get_config(module, flags=flags)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/ios/ios.py\", line 117, in get_config\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_d8od9psi/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py\", line 149, in __rpc__\nansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: show running-config all\r\n                ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\nDE003SW01#\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Comment: Hello! An advice on your title: "what is the problem with this" is not a good title, try to be more specific. Please, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try removing the 'connection: local' line if the host your are attempting to connect to is not the same as where the ansible playbook is running.

Answer (score 0):

For connection at the top of your playbook I believe it should be `ansible.netcommon.network_cli`. Also the `ansible_network_os` variable needs to have the OS of your switch, for cisco it would be cisco.ios.ios. I found this tutorial super helpful: [Ansible tutorial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_playbook.html#run-your-first-network-ansible-command).